# Openh264 throws UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, unsatisfiedlinkerror, openh264

Today we got a strange crash. During the first installation the app downloads and unzips openh264 to the internal directory of the app, happens on a Schedulers.io() thread from rxAndroid.
This is the first crash of this kind (>5k installations) and I found this [link](https://www.nowsecure.com/blog/2015/08/10/world-writable-code-is-bad-mmmmkay/) (very interesting blog by the way) with a matching error message. I'm not sure if really someone tried to replace the openH264 lib or if someone tried to install the apk file on a x86 device. I'm still using 1.4 of openH264 and have read the 1.5 release notes. There is no hint of security fixes.

Some more details about the device:

Android: 4.3

Manufacturer: Samsung

Model: GT-I9300

And finally, here is the crash log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:62)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/path/files/libopenh264.so" has bad ELF magic
at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:330)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:511)
at path.BeatMarker.init(BeatMarker.java:33)
at path.fragments.main.MainFragment.onOpenH264Done(MainFragment.java:475)
at path.fragments.main.MainPresenterImpl.onOpenH264Done(MainPresenterImpl.java:25)
at path.fragments.main.MainLoaderImpl$1.onCompleted(MainLoaderImpl.java:61)
at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onCompleted(SafeSubscriber.java:81)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.pollQueue(OperatorObserveOn.java:201)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber$2.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:170)
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
... 9 more
```

I'm pretty sure, the crash happens here:

```
at path.BeatMarker.init(BeatMarker.java:33)
```

These are the lines:

```
File libOpenH264File = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "libopenh264.so");
System.load(libOpenH264File.getAbsolutePath()); //line 33
```

Gets called, when the download and unzip is completed.

Can the error occur, while the lib is downloading and the network connection get lost?

Any help or hint is welcome, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Can you guys give me a heads up for the process of setting up OpenH264 codec in Android for use in my WebRTC app. Thanks in advance.